# Unable to deploy Spring Web Service on JBoss server

Tags: web-services, spring, maven, jboss

I was testing my Spring WS on `VMWare vFabric` server where my WS works fine, now i want to migrate to `JBOSS 4.2.3.GA` and after short period of time i came across problem I can't solve.. I get this exception at Server startup:

```
11:07:01,828 WARN  [ServiceController] Problem starting service jboss:service=TransactionManager
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogConfigurationException
    at com.arjuna.common.util.logging.LogFactory.setupLogSystem(LogFactory.java:392)
    at com.arjuna.common.util.logging.LogFactory.getLogNoi18n(LogFactory.java:190)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.logging.tsLogger.<clinit>(tsLogger.java:58)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.objectstore.ShadowingStore.<init>(ShadowingStore.java:840)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.objectstore.ShadowNoFileLockStore.<init>(ShadowNoFileLockStore.java:155)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.objectstore.HashedStore.<init>(HashedStore.java:268)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.objectstore.HashedActionStore.<init>(HashedActionStore.java:172)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.objectstore.HashedActionStore.<init>(HashedActionStore.java:167)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.objectstore.HashedActionStore.create(HashedActionStore.java:100)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.objectstore.HashedActionStoreSetup.createVoid(HashedActionStoreSetup.java:49)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.gandiva.inventory.StaticInventory.createVoid(StaticInventory.java:76)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.gandiva.inventory.Inventory.createVoid(Inventory.java:84)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.objectstore.ObjectStore.<init>(ObjectStore.java:128)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TxControl.getStore(TxControl.java:133)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.recovery.ActionStatusService.<init>(ActionStatusService.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:501)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:350)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:303)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.recovery.TransactionStatusManager.start(TransactionStatusManager.java:149)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.recovery.TransactionStatusManager.<init>(TransactionStatusManager.java:78)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TxControl.<clinit>(TxControl.java:312)
    at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.jta.TransactionManagerService.startService(TransactionManagerService.java:139)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
    at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:304)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:766)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:482)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:508)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

It looks like server want to load library `org/apache/commons/logging` from its own directory which look like:
[image]

and my dependency:

```
<!-- ============ CORE DEPENDENCIES =============== -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    <!-- ============ SPRINGFRAMEWORK DEPENDENCIES =============== -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>

    <!-- ============ JAVAX DEPENDENCIES =============== -->        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

     <!-- ============ HIBERNATE DEPENDENCIES =============== -->       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    <!-- ============ c3p0 DEPENDENCIES =============== --> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    <!-- ============ POSTGRESQL DEPENDENCIES =============== -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
    <!-- ============ LOGGING DEPENDENCIES =============== -->  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> 
    <!-- ============ CAMEL DEPENDENCIES =============== -->        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>${camel-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
            <version>${camel-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${camel-version}</version>
        </dependency>
    <!-- ============ ACTIVEMQ DEPENDENCIES =============== --> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
            <version>${activemq-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-pool</artifactId>
            <version>${activemq-version}</version>
        </dependency>
    <!-- ============ XBEAN DEPENDENCIES =============== -->        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xbean</groupId>
            <artifactId>xbean-spring</artifactId>
            <version>3.7</version>
        </dependency> 
    <!-- ============ SUN DEPENDENCIES =============== -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

I am missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that `JBOSS 4.2.3.GA` have already some libraries included in his base package. Error you are getting is related to package version mismatch which is kind of a not surprise because `4.2.3` is an old version, and what comes with it - it have old version of packages included. Check the `library` direction on Your server and then remove from there packages you are using in your app.